# Telegram Bot "chat not found" when replying to user

Tags: telegram

We have a scenario where the user starts a conversation by calling our telegram bot 
The following message data is received from telegram when the user calls our bot:

```json
{{
  "update_id": 402509014,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 754,
    "from": {
      "id": 123456789,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "john",
      "last_name": "Yh",
      "language_code": "en"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 123456789  ,
      "first_name": "john  ",
      "last_name": "Yh",
      "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1635405621,
    "text": "start/"
  }
}}
```

However when we try to answer the user with a post call from server side we receive an error message:

```
url - https://api.telegram.org/bot123321123321:token/sendPhoto

body - { "chat_id": " 123456789    ", "photo": "url2photo"}

response: error 400 "Bad Request: chat not found"
```

This only happens for some of the users while the rest are able to receive the messages. Is it possible that the chat id of this user was sent incorrectly by telegram on the first message? Or maybe this user has privacy settings?
The same error is received when trying to make the same call from postman

Comment: `chat not found` error typically occurs when using an invalid chat_id or trying to message a user who has not initiated a conversation with your bot yet. Highly unlikely receiving a wrong chat_id from incoming update.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add more details and the code your trying to fix.

Comment: @Isaac, did you figure out the issue. I also face the same problem. For some interacted users only I am getting chat not found error

Comment: @AshikMydeen Hi, no unfortunately we still didn't figure out why on only some users we are unable to reply back. I was guessing that it might be some different settings with those users or maybe a bug in telegram. And as you can see there are poor responses here so it's probably not common at all..

Answer (score 0):

If a user doesn't send any message to your bot, your bot doesn't send message to the user.You can use Authorization bot to send message.if users authenticated with your bot, they already sent your bot a message.Consequently, you can send message to users if they signed-in with your telegram bot.